# I want to replace all the usernames with a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

please help me. I am having a problem creating a link to all the usernames in the page. I use javascript to replace the names but i can only replace one name.

for example, i have 4 usernames: usera, userb, userc and userd. everytime these words show in the page, i want them to be replaced with:

```
usera = <a href="link.php?user=usera">usera</a>
userb = <a href="link.php?user=userb">userb</a>
```

and so on.

this is my code, but i can only replace one.

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>replacing usernames to link</h1>

  <p>
   usera, userb, userc, userd, userk, userks
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript

```
var $els = $('body *');

$els.each(function(){

  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/usera/g, '<a href="link.php?user=usera">usera</a>'));

  //$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/userb/g, '<a href="link.php?user=userb">userb</a>'));


});
```

only one user, i want to create an array but I do not know the syntax. please help me.

Comment: `replace(/usera/g` ? you are replacing only the usera

Comment: I see jQuery there

Comment: fix this at source that generates that html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better try with [`map()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj-ofio9pbUAhVGtI8KHerzA5sQFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNHaY16WQvsRJFKI1AN9YJUvUNjsCg&sig2=CgxLkuRmSOKjBaayP1MHcg) array function

```js
var $els = $('body p').text().trim().split(',');
var res = $els.map(function(a) {
  return '<a href="link.php?user=' + a + '">' + a + '</a>'
})
$('body').append(res.join('<br>'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>replacing usernames to link</h1>
<p> usera, userb, userc, userd, userk, userks</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Extend the check for letters `a-d` with a character class and this would work, you don't need an array.

```
$(this).html($(this).text().replace(/user([a-d])/g, '<a href="link.php?user=user$1">user$1</a>'));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/24c6t03g/